# Multiplayer Game in android, iPhone and web

Tags: android, ios, html, web

I need to create a multiplayer game which will run in Android, iOS and web. I need real-time multiplayer api like google play services. But Real-time multiplayer is currently only supported for the Android platform. Is there any other frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience [Photon](http://www.exitgames.com/Pricing) is great. They have a free version and when your game booms, you can afford the cost.