# Google Play Games Services multiplayer iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, google-play-services

Is possible create a multiplayer session between iOS and Android devices with Google Play Games Services?

For each platform is possible, but it is possible to combine them?

This question is outdate:
[Multiplayer Game in android, iPhone and web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881118/multiplayer-game-in-android-iphone-and-web)
because Real-time multiplayer is currently supported for the iOS and web platforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is YES,

You can create rooms with Android and iOS users

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays it's not possible. iOS support is deprecated, Google is not supporting it any more:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/focusing-our-google-play-games-services.html

So, it's not possible to use 'Google Play Games Services multiplayer' for iOS.

EDIT: 'Google Play Games Services multiplayer' will be also unsupported on Android:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9469745

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21063140)

Comment: I think it was clear enough: "iOS support is deprecated", but I add some more clarification just in case.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the complains. The question is: "Is possible create a multiplayer session between iOS and Android devices with Google Play Games Services?" -> My answer is: "Nowadays it's not possible." I think it's a correct answer to the question, I just edited the answer to be more clear, but the main fact is still the same. No iOS support.